# ebay finding api finditemsbykeywords pagination problem

Tags: ebay-api

I tried the following calls:

https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&keywords=waschbecken&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-DE&outputSelector(0)=ItemSpecifics&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100&paginationInput.pageNumber=2

then on the ebay API explorer for the post request body,

```
<findItemsByKeywordsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
  <keywords>waschbecken</keywords>
  <paginationInput>
    <entriesPerPage>100</entriesPerPage>
    <pageNumber>2</pageNumber>
  </paginationInput>
</findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
```

but I do not get 100 searchResult count per page, in Postman I get 32 searchResult and in API explorer 56; furthermore 2nd page forward I do not get any searchResult count, I am trying to understand is there something wrong that I am writing in the call or there is some another problem or any parameter I am missing.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I did not update on the question, I forgot about it.

The problem was not with the pagination, the problem is the variants.

Simply explained, the output of the query doesn't count for the variants listed on the Ebay search by the same seller. If you have from a same seller the same product with the different variant, the query does not show the variants from those product from the same seller just different variant, as it would if you do an ebay search.

The mechanism of the query is different as that of the product search on Ebay.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running into this problem. I am guessing that the pagination results are for the entire store, but not for the search by keywords....Seems like they dropped the ball on this.